# Return from digression early in Watson Assistant

Tags: ibm-cloud, ibm-watson, watson-assistant

Currently, I can digress and return back to where I left off after the flow is complete. Great, now to make all the scenarios as realistic as possible, I have created a "Nevermind" intent if the user changes their mind during the digression. How would I be able to return from the digression early if that intent is detected?

Comment: Could you add more details? You probably have followed an example like here https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/assistant?topic=assistant-tutorial-digressions, right?

Comment: @data_henrik Right, that's what I followed. Let's say I'm a retailer. I have a parent dialog node triggered by "I'm looking for product x." Then there's another parent node, literally anything, let's just say start return. So the flow I'm looking for would be customer asking questions about product x, decides to ask the assistant about returning some other product, and finally changes mind which brings us right back to where we were before we asked for a refund. All I see in the documentation is being able to return from a digression once the last dialog node is reached